# Java ArrayList Elements are overridden by Last Added Element

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to code an algorithm that can learn by his experiences (in the game connect four). For that I wanted to save all the single steps in a List. But if I am adding Elements to my List, Every Element in the List gets overridden by the Element i am adding. I have no clue why this is like this and even after 1Hour searching I dont know why, because there is no static field in my Runde.java. The code is here: (Im German so dont be suprised by that weird names for the variables)

```
package me;

public class Runde{

    private int[][] spielfeld;
    private int[][] x= new int[7][5];
    private int lastx;
    private int lasty;
    public Runde(int[][] spielfeld1, int xi, int jetzgzuege, int y){
        spielfeld=spielfeld1;

        lastx=xi;
        x[xi][4]=jetzgzuege;
        lasty=y;
    }
    public boolean equal(int[][] spielfeld){
        if(spielfeld.equals(spielfeld)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    public void finishround(boolean sieg, int geszuege){
        x[lastx][0]+=1;
        if(sieg){
            x[lastx][1]+=1;
            x[lastx][2]+=geszuege;
        }else{
            x[lastx][3]+=geszuege;
        }

    }
    public int[][] getSpielfeld(){
        return spielfeld;
    }
    public int[][] getData(){
        return x;
    }
    public int getlastx(){
        return lastx;
    }
    public int getlasty(){
        return lasty;
    }
}


static ArrayList<Runde> liste= new ArrayList<Runde>();
static ArrayList<Runde> Steps= new ArrayList<Runde>();


static void erzeugeGen(){
    int[][] spielfeld=leeresSperzeugen();
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int zug=0;
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(2);
    boolean player;
    if(rand==1){
     player = true;
    }else{
     player=false;
    }
    while(!winner(spielfeld,x,y) && zug<42){
        zug++;
        player=!player;
        Runde r;
        if(player){
                r= Computerzug(spielfeld.clone(),1,zug); // If i have a look in to the spielfeld in this element, its fine
                Steps.add(r); // But after adding like this, its overridden :(
        }else{
                r= Computerzug(spielfeld.clone(),2,zug);
        }
        x=r.getlastx();
        y=r.getlasty();
        if(player){
            spielfeld[y][x]=1;
        }else{
            spielfeld[y][x]=2;
        }
    }
    if(zug<42){
    GenAuswerten(zug,player);
    zuege+=zug;
    }else{
        gen--;
    }

}

static void GenAuswerten(int zug, boolean win){
    for(Runde r: Steps){
        r.finishround(win, zug);
        ArrayList<Runde> removal = new ArrayList<Runde>();
        for(Runde r2 : liste){
            if(r2.equal(r.getSpielfeld())){
                removal.add(r2);
            }
        }
        for(Runde r3: removal){
            liste.remove(r3);
        }
    }

  for(Runde r: Steps){
        liste.add(0,r);
    }
  Steps.clear();
}
```

Comment: A multidimensional array is not a `List`.

Comment: There is no ArrayList in the code shown

Comment: I am not able to find out Java ArrayList in above code? ;-)

Comment: Whoops forgot a bit of code... Editing right now

Comment: Added the whole Main class now^^

Comment: @Fabianv.d.W Can you just post the relevant code and not your entire class. Your chances of getting help will increase as you make it easier for someone to read through your problem.

Comment: To get better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Ok added the 2 Main Methods that are saving the data and added they way i initialized the Lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to clone the 2nd level arrays when you clone this

> r= Computerzug(spielfeld.clone(),1,zug);

so the correct code is

```
 int spielfeldclone[][] = new int[spielfeld.length][];
 int i = 0;
 for(int[] spielfeldArray: spielfeld){
      spielfeldclone[i] =spielfeldArray.clone()lone();
      i++;
}
r= Computerzug(spielfeldclone,1,zug);
```

the reason is that you are doing shallow copy of 2d array

and remeber 2d array is an array of array

normaly clone() of any array would work if the array was of primitive type like int

but here the array you are cloning contain arrays

that mean you will get new references to the same 2nd level array object

So

> spielfeld[0] == spielfeld.clone()[0]
>
> is true

since both spielfeld[0] and spielfeld.clone()[0] point to same object

now to resolve that we needed to do shallow copy of the inner arrays each one alone which resulted in deep copy

Comment: And i actually understand it now :D Its because 2D Array cant be cloned just by .clone(), since they have annother Arrays in them. Thank you.

Comment: If you feel this answer is good answer for your question please mark the checkbox to make it as an answer. Thanks